# Processing 2.2 not Running Program Properly

Tags: java, processing

I am writing a 3D game in Processing that starts using a menu. Once you press "Play", the camera is moved to another position for the actual game play. Since upgrading from Processing 2.1.1 to 2.2, I am having an issue with the code responsible for moving the camera. When running the program with Processing 2.1.1, the board looks as it should (see first screenshot). After upgrading to Processing 2.2 and using the same exact code, the resulting switch from menu to gameplay has been messed up (see second screenshot). What happens in Processing 2.2 is that whenever you press the "Play" button the proper camera position, seen in screenshot 1, flashes quickly, and the camera then moves up as seen in screenshot 2. Since this issue appears to be happening since upgrading the version of Processing I am using, I am attributing this change to a bug in Processing. Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on here? I have been able to determine that the camera does not actually move, but rather the game board itself, which I have removed from these screenshots so you cannot see the game, is actually either not loading or disappearing despite no changes in code from 2.1.1 to 2.2. I posted this question on the Processing forums on Wednesday but did not receive any response.

Processing 2.1.1 - Good
[image: Processing 2.1.1 - Good]

Processing 2.2 - Bad
[image: Processing 2.2 - Bad]

Comment: The description of the problem and the screenshots are great and all but are we supposed to just throw guesses your way? Where's the code? How did you implement the camera? There's about zero information to go on, I am not surprised you didn't get a reply in Processing forums. `Camera quickly flashes`...not sure what that means. Post relevant code if you want help.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo Will post the code as soon as I can. I am stripping the program down to the basics because there is a ton of code that only makes it harder to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: @DavidB +1, in stripping it down to make it easier for us, it also makes it more likely for you to see the problem (or a solution) yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I cannot figure out why a previously acceptable camera position for the program suddenly moved after upgrading from Processing 2.1.1 to 2.2, I was able to fix the problem by spending tons of time tweaking the x, y, and z coordinates that the camera is positioned at. There's something magical about the coordinates that I had before that caused the camera to go haywire. Any ideas about how or why this happened would be appreciated, but as I have solved the problem, I am satisfied with the solution.